# How to escape HCL string containing ${aws:username} in "Resource" section?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

**How to escape HCL string containing ${aws:username} in "Resource" section?**

I currently use Terraform version 0.9.9 to create AWS policies in a main.tf file in following way:

```
resource "aws_iam_group_policy" "AllowIndividualUserToSeeTheirAccountInformation" {
      name  = "AllowIndividualUserToSeeTheirAccountInformation"
      group = "${aws_iam_group.pr_faas_developers.id}"

      policy = <<EOF
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Action": [
                "iam:ChangePassword",
                "iam:CreateLoginProfile",
                "iam:DeleteLoginProfile",
                "iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy",
                "iam:GetAccountSummary",
                "iam:GetLoginProfile",
                "iam:UpdateLoginProfile"
          ],
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource":
          [
                "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:user/${aws:username}"
            ]

        }
      ]
    }
    EOF
    }
```

When doing so, Terraform tries to interpolate `${aws:username}` and terraform is going to fail as follows

```
terraform.exe plan
Failed to load root config module: Error loading D:\amazonaws-root-master\main.t
f: Error reading config for aws_iam_group_policy[AllowIndividualUserToSeeTheirAc
countInformation]: parse error at 17:51: expected "}" but found ":"
```

When I'm escaping the resource string as follows:

```
"Resource":
      [
            "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:user/\\$\\{aws\\:username\\}"
        ]
```

`"terraform plan"` and `"terraform apply"` is going to work fine but the result within AWS show policy is:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
            "iam:ChangePassword",
            "iam:CreateLoginProfile",
            "iam:DeleteLoginProfile",
            "iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy",
            "iam:GetAccountSummary",
            "iam:GetLoginProfile",
            "iam:UpdateLoginProfile"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource":
      [
            "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:user/\\$\\{aws:username\\}"
        ]

    }
  ]
}
```

which is different from the expected outcome:

```
 {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Action": [
                "iam:ChangePassword",
                "iam:CreateLoginProfile",
                "iam:DeleteLoginProfile",
                "iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy",
                "iam:GetAccountSummary",
                "iam:GetLoginProfile",
                "iam:UpdateLoginProfile"
          ],
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource":
          [
                "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:user/${aws:username}"
            ]

        }
      ]
    }
```

Is there any solution to escape `"arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:user/${aws:username}"` within the terraform main.tf file for the desired outcome?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can fix it by double dollar `$$`

refer:

[terraform interpolation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html)

> You can escape interpolation with double dollar signs: $${foo} will be rendered as a literal ${foo}.

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/2965

Answer (score 3):

Recently running into similar string literal issue, copy [the response](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-fastly/issues/210#issuecomment-589267611) into here to help more folks.

Note, this still applies with Terraform 0.12.

> "In both quoted and heredoc string expressions, Terraform supports template sequences that begin with `${` and `%{`."
>
> "To include these sequences literally without beginning a template sequence, double the leading character: `$${` or `%%{`."
>
> Please have a look at the [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#string-literals) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/2.69.0/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document#context-variable-interpolation

> The IAM policy document format allows context variables to be interpolated into various strings within a statement. The native IAM policy document format uses ${...}-style syntax that is in conflict with Terraform's interpolation syntax, so this data source instead uses &{...} syntax for interpolations that should be processed by AWS rather than by Terraform.

so you can do

```
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::${var.s3_bucket_name}/home/&{aws:username}",
      "arn:aws:s3:::${var.s3_bucket_name}/home/&{aws:username}/*",
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions:

1. Escape that variable in shell script using an extra `$` before it. For example, `PROJECT=$${project}`
2. Add that variable as `project = "$project"` under the list of variables for file in terraform script and it will replace `${project}` with `$project` and the script will still work.